# Testing a Display

Tags: display, ribbon-cable

Currently working on a design project for school where a display is needed.

I need help figuring out what parts I need to split the 10 wire ribbon cable that comes of the LCD into 10 jumper cable to go into a breadboard for testing.

The closest thing I found was this
 https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/710-68711014022
But I will still need to connect jumper cables to that as well

LCD being used :https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/?qs=La0%252b8xZSm19d3Mbp4mkNrQ%3d%3d

LCD data sheet: https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/365/LS013B7DH03%20SPEC_SMA-1203020.pdf

Comment: Unless its a display that's used a lot by DIYers, you are unlikely to find an adapter with wires for breadboarding ready made.

Comment: You can find a suitable connector, as stated on page 23 (PDF page 25) of the datasheet here: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex-llc/0514411093/WM6474CT-ND/1089691

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite clear from the datasheet what connector is mating the one on the display. Did you read it through?
Page 9 of the pdf:
[image]
Page 25 of the pdf:
[image]

Using the appropriate FPC/FFC connector that corresponds to these two suggestions, you could make a small breakout board yourself that you can mount the connector to, and have pin headers to put in your breadboard if you're so inclined.

If you don't want to make it yourself, you can get FPC/FFC adapter boards from [Proto Advantage](http://www.proto-advantage.com/store/product_info.php?products_id=3400010)